# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" despite same data type

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I wanted to add a foreign key `Enrols.mid` that references `Member.id`, but after a few tries (adding index, creating keys, googleing) it still isn't working.
The two columns have the exact same data type, why adding a foreign key isn't working?

```
MariaDB [alumni]> alter table Enrols add foreign key (`mid`) references Member.id;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `alumni`.`#sql-31e_21d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
MariaDB [alumni]> desc Member;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | char(8)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| cName     | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| eName     | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender    | char(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| org       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pos       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hobby     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| issueDate | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| note      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [alumni]> desc Enrols;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| aid   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mid   | char(8) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| paid  | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [alumni]>
```

Comment: Should it not be `references Member (id);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Damien_The_Unbeliever said in their comment, it should be `references Member(id)` .

Your `.` syntax means: *reference table `id` in Schema `Member`* (But you want to reference **column** `id` in **table** `Member`.